# parameter isn't destroyed when argument throws exception?

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following toy code:

```cpp
class X {};

class Y {
public:
    Y() { cout << "Y ctor\n"; }
    ~Y() { cout << "Y dtor\n"; }
};

int gun() {
    throw X{};
    return 42;
}

void fun(Y yy, int i) {}

int main()
{
    Y a;
    cout << "--------\n";
    try
    {
        fun(a, gun());
    }
    catch (const X&)
    {
        cout << "catched\n";
    }
    cout << "--------\n";
}
```

The outputs of this are as follows:

```
Y ctor
--------
catched
--------
Y dtor
```

May I ask why the destructor of the parameter `yy` (copy initialized by `a`) is not called?

---

Same outputs are produced when I switch the order of the arguments (i.e. using `void fun(int i, Y yy) {}` and `fun(gun(), a);`), so I don't think it is because of the undefined order of evaluation of function arguments.

---

Update: see [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1M3YsW3Pv)

Comment: The order of parameter evaluations is unspecified. In you case, `gun()` is called before `Y(a)`.

Comment: And as can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/x79qrbrh3) gcc and clang do it in different order in this case.

Comment: *so I don't think it is because of the undefined order of evaluation of function arguments.* -- You made a mistake that many made, and that is to determine C++ rules by how a particular program runs.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for your demo. I'm using visual studio, and I think msvc never calls the destructor in either order. May I ask why?

Comment: @CPPL Here's a demo [including MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/fn4G4Kze1). It uses the same order as gcc in this scenario.

Comment: It doesn't call the destructor because it never copy constructed an object in the first place

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried the previous code you wrote (i.e. comment out the copy constructor. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MGjheq6cG)) and the msvc outputs are different.

Comment: @CPPL Interesting. It seems like adding a user-defined copy constructor makes MSVC actually instantiate an `Y` in one of the cases - but without a user-defined copy constructor - it'll skip instantiating an `Y` in both cases. I guess it's allowed to order the arguments differently in each call if it pleases so `gun()` gets called first in both cases.

Comment: Compiler might be smart, notices that `a` is never used again, and doesn't bother with copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no sequencing rules between the argument expressions in a function call and/or the initialization of function parameters until C++17. Since C++17 there are some rules which however still do not establish any ordering between the individual arguments.

As a consequence only the indeterminate sequencing rules for function calls apply and the compiler is free to choose to either call `gun()` first and construct `Y yy` afterwards or the other way around. Due to the indeterminate sequencing rules the compiler is however not allowed to interleave these calls.

So, if the compiler chooses the former order of evaluation, `Y yy`'s constructor is never called before the exception is thrown and hence its destructor also won't (and shouldn't) be called.

If the compiler decides to do it the other way around, then `Y yy` will have been constructed when the exception is thrown and its destructor will then also be called.

You can verify this by adding output in the copy constructor as well. You will see that either the copy constructor is never called and `yy` does not have a destructor called or both will be called.

You cannot control which of the two scenarios happens. The choice is *unspecified*, meaning that the compiler could also just choose it randomly at runtime. Reordering the arguments will not help. In practice there will be some rules in the compiler to decide the order at compile-time, probably in an order that is beneficial to optimization. It may be inconsistent between multiple equivalent calls as well.

Comment: _"the compiler is however not allowed to interleave these calls"_ - Does that mean that doing [what MSVC is doing](https://godbolt.org/z/zbc9bcnsc) isn't allowed? Or is it allowed because there are two different functions involved? Without a user-defined copy ctor, it doesn't instantiate a `Y` in neither `fun1(a, gun());` nor `fun2(gun(), a);`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, what I mean is just the general sequencing guarantee for function calls: That the execution of a function body doesn't interleave with the execution of another function body, meaning that the compiler can not execute parts of the body for `gun()`, then parts of the `yy` constructor call and then continue again in `gun()`. A function call is at least _indeterminately sequenced_ with any other evaluation in an expression.

Comment: @TedLyngmo There is no guarantee that the order is the same in multiple calls, even to the same function. There is also nothing stating that it is implementation-defined, so there doesn't need to be some documented rule for the decision either.

Comment: Great, that's what I thought!